# Django view HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, http-redirect

I have two functions in views.py:

**First function**

```
def upload_blob(request, iterator, interview_id, candidate_id, question_id):
    try:
        interview_obj = Interview.objects.get(id=interview_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        interview_obj = None
    current_interview = interview_obj
    if request.method == 'POST':
        //do some operation
        iterator = str(int(iterator) + 1)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('candidate:show_question', kwargs={'iterator': iterator,'interview_id':current_interview.id,'question_id':question_id}))
    else:
        return render(request, 'candidate/record_answer.html')
```

**Second function**

```
def show_question(request, iterator, interview_id, question_id):
    try:
        interview_obj = Interview.objects.get(id=interview_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        interview_obj = None
    current_interview = interview_obj
    current_question_id = InterviewQuestion.objects.filter(interview_id=interview_obj)[int(iterator)].question_id.id
    current_question = Question.objects.get(id=current_question_id)
    **//Here if redirected from first function, I should display show_question page with incremented iterator value, but currently it's going in loop**
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('candidate:show_question', kwargs={'iterator': iterator,'interview_id':current_interview.id,'question_id':question_id}))
    context = {'iterator':iterator, 'current_interview':current_interview,'current_question':current_question,}
    return render(request, 'candidate/show_question.html', context)
```

- **Flow of operation is like this:

  - show_question function is called with iterator = 0 and it renders show_question.html. User does some operation on this page that calls
    the function upload_blob through POST request.
  - upload_blob does some operation after checking request.method is POST, increases iterator value by 1 and redirects to show_question
    method.
  - This time show_question receives iterator =1 and is supposed to show show_question page with iterator=1 (without putting redirects in
    loop). Again user should do some operation on show_question.html and
    upload_blob should be called through POST request.

I am currently facing the problem of loop and repeated redirects in show_question**

Comment: You don't have any if statements there. You will *always* redirect, and since you never change any of the arguments, you will always redirect back to exactly the same URL. I don't really understand why you redirect at all inside show_question, to be honest.

Comment: yes Daniel, you are right, actually after iterator becomes 1, request is going to show_question but html is not getting rendered. I am using celery task in asynchronous mode.